# How to hide input fields of a form which are not checked and display only checked ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have a form with many input fields. On each input change there is a checkbox which get checked. Now i want to show only those fields which are checked on button click and hide others. I am not sure what will be the best way to achieve that behaviour. Later on next button click i will submit only checked fields.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input value="1" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="checkbox-1"></label>                           
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="" id="field-1" name="field-1">
    <label class="form-label">Field 1</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input value="1" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="checkbox-2"></label>                           
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="" id="field-2" name="field-2">
    <label class="form-label">Field 2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input value="1" name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="checkbox-3"></label>                           
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="" id="field-3" name="field-3">
    <label class="form-label">Field 3</label>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" >click</button>
```

Following jQuery function is to check checkbox on input field change

```
$('.form-group').find('input[type=text], select').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, it can help you: https://api.jquery.com/has/
Like this:

```
$('.form-group:not(:has(input:checked))').hide();
```

Comment: Small fix, check again please

Comment: its still hiding all the form groups

Answer (score 0):

try this one line of js code

```
<button type="button" id="btn">click</button>

$('#btn').on('click', function () {
   $('[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').closest(".form-group").hide()
});
```

Comment: it will hide the checked input field

Comment: actually now its hiding all the fields if there is no check

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example.  Alternatively, you might also look at Select2 plugin.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //hide by default
        $('#field1').hide();

        $('#check1').click(function(e){
            if ($('#check1').prop('checked')){
                $('#field1').show();
            }else{
                $(#field1).hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<body>

    <form>

        <label for="check1">click me</label>
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox"/>
        <input id="field1" type="text"/>

    </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I tried for a solution

```js
$('.form-group').find('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  //hide input
  $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.field').attr('style', 'display:none');
  //hide checkbox
  $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.checkbox').attr('style', 'display:none');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input value="1" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" checked='true' />
    <label for="checkbox-1"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="" id="field-1" name="field-1">
    <label class="form-label">Field 1</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input value="1" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" checked='true' />
    <label for="checkbox-2"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="" id="field-2" name="field-2">
    <label class="form-label">Field 2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input value="1" name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox" checked='true' />
    <label for="checkbox-3"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="" id="field-3" name="field-3">
    <label class="form-label">Field 3</label>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="submit">click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution for your question.

On button **click event** you can check the value of each checkbox which is checked or not!

On the basis of **is(':checked')** hide/show the input field

```js
$('.form-group').find('input[type=text], select').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
});

$("#btn").click(function(){
  var count = 0;
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(ind,value){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      count++;
    }
  });
  //check if atleast one check box is selected
  if(count > 0){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(ind,value){
      if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $(this).parent().next().hide();

      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input value="1" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="checkbox-1"></label>                           
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="" id="field-1" name="field-1">
    <label class="form-label">Field 1</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input value="1" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="checkbox-2"></label>                           
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="" id="field-2" name="field-2">
    <label class="form-label">Field 2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input value="1" name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="checkbox-3"></label>                           
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="" id="field-3" name="field-3">
    <label class="form-label">Field 3</label>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="btn">click</button>
```

Comment: if you click button without check any input , will hide all fields

Comment: I have added the validation for checking if at least one checkbox is checked then only hide unchecked